# SQL Query for Group by with two sorting values and count the equal values

Tags: mysql, sql

For example i have table data below:

```
    Date          branch     sale     profit
    Jan 1, 2014    A         10          5
    Jan 2, 2014    A         11          6
    Jan 3, 2014    A         20          9
    Feb 1, 2014    A         11          4
    Feb 2, 2014    B         20          10
    Feb 3, 2014    C         12          6
    Mar 1, 2014    A         25          15
    Mar 2, 2014    B         60          30
    Mar 3, 2014    B         40          20
```

I have successfully group these data by month and sum the sale and profit.
See my sql query below.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b') as date, SUM(sale) as sale, SUM(profit) as profit FROM sales_report GROUP BY MONTH(date) ORDER BY MONTH(date)
```

I have a result value below

```
Date    branch     sale     profit
Jan      A         41          20
Feb      A         43          20
Mar      A         125         65
```

What i want to achieve here is to pick the branch with latest date and stay the month with ascending order
and i also want to add field to count the branch. i want these result below. please help

```
Date    branch     sale     profit   Count
Jan      A         41          20      1
Feb      C         43          20      3
Mar      B         125         65      2
```

Comment: your table has data like `Jan 1, Feb 1, Mar 1` whereas your results are grouped by month `Jan, Feb, Mar`. And your query just groups by date, not specifically by month. Are you sure the data you provided and the expected output is correct?

Comment: Actually i just put it as a sample, if you want this is the original sql i have for your reference       SELECT DATE_FORMAT(date,'%b') as date, SUM(sale) as sale, SUM(profit) as profit FROM sales_report GROUP BY MONTH(date) ORDER BY MONTH(date)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want `count(distinct)` for the counting column.  For the branch, you can use `group_concat()`/`substring_index()`:

```
SELECT year(date), month(date),
       substring_index(group_concat(branch order by date desc), ',', 1) as last_branch,
       SUM(sale) as sale, SUM(profit) as profit,
       count(distinct branch) as NumBranches
FROM sales_report
GROUP BY year(date), month(date)
ORDER BY min(date);
```

Comment: Working!. Thank you so much! @Gordon Linoff